# Backup of data on iCloud

Tags: icloud, backup, data

I use iCloud as backup storage for my iPad, iPhone and PC. But if something were to happen to iCloud I would lose ALL my data.

Is there any way of backing up iCloud data (especially backups) and if so where and how?

Answer (score 1):

For complete belt & braces, you really need a minimum of 3 distinct locations for any data you consider 'permanent'.

1. Your computer.
2. a local backup
3. an off-site backup.

There can be some element of redundancy in this.

You can backup your iPhone to your computer, via iTunes.

Your computer then ought to be backed up to either another computer in the same building, or to a hard drive, connected especially for that purpose. For Mac, Time Machine is the perfect solution. For Windows, something like [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/en-gb/personal/). 
This ought to be good enough right up to the point the house burns down ;)

To be secure even in that remote eventuality, your computer, already containing your safety backup of your iCloud/iPhone data, can then separately be backed up to another online service such as [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com/cloud-backup.html). Acronis also have a cloud solution - I've not tried this myself, but it may be worth investigating.